# ValueError at /pembayaran/ ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import pembayaranform

class pembayaran(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = pembayaranform
        fields='__all__'
```

what's wrong?

Comment: It is `model = pembayaranform`, not `models = ...`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: ValueError at /pembayaran/
ModelForm has no model class specified.
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
ModelForm has no model class specified.

Comment: pembayaran' object has no attribute 'get' @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @NetaAulya: you likly also use the form the wrong way in the view(s).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem from . import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import pembayaran

#Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def pembayaran_function(request):
    form=pembayaran(request)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=pembayaran(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request, 'pembayaran.html', context)

Comment: `form=pembayaran(request)` does not make much sense. Please [edit] your question, and post the given views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i've edit it. but sill not work